# If $\mathbf{A}_i=\lambda_i\mathbf{a}+\mu_i\mathbf{b}+\nu_i\mathbf{c}$, then $\mathbf{A}_1\cdot\left(\mathbf{A}_2\times\mathbf{A}_3\right)=$

Tags: solution-verification, vectors, vector-analysis, inner-products, cross-product

Here is Prob. 2.43 in the book *Vector Analysis & Cartesian Tensors* by D. E. Bourne and P. C. Kendall, 3rd edition:

> If
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \mathbf{A}_1 &= \lambda_1 \mathbf{a} + \mu_1 \mathbf{b} + \nu_1 \mathbf{c}, \\
> \mathbf{A}_2 &= \lambda_2 \mathbf{a} + \mu_2 \mathbf{b} + \nu_2 \mathbf{c}, \\
> \mathbf{A}_3 &= \lambda_3 \mathbf{a} + \mu_3 \mathbf{b} + \nu_3 \mathbf{c},
> \end{align}
> $$
> show that
> $$
> \mathbf{A}_1 \cdot \left( \mathbf{A}_2 \times \mathbf{A}_3 \right) = \left| \begin{matrix} \lambda_1 & \mu_1 & \nu_1 \\ \lambda_2 & \mu_2 & \nu_2 \\ \lambda_3 & \mu_3 & \nu_3 \end{matrix} \right| \mathbf{a} \cdot ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ). 
> $$

My Attempt:

> In what follows, we will be using the following identities:
> $$
> \mathbf{a} \cdot ( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} ) = \mathbf{b} \cdot ( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} ) =  \mathbf{b} \cdot ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) = \mathbf{c} \cdot ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) = \mathbf{c} \cdot ( \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{a} ) = \mathbf{a} \cdot ( \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{a} ) = 0,
> $$
> and also that
> $$
> \mathbf{a} \cdot ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) = \mathbf{b} \cdot ( \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{a} ) = \mathbf{c} \cdot ( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} ).
> $$

> Using the distributive property of the dot and the cross products, we obtain
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \qquad  \mathbf{A}_1 \cdot \left( \mathbf{A}_2 \times \mathbf{A}_3 \right) \\ 
> &= \left( \lambda_1 \mathbf{a} + \mu_1 \mathbf{b} + \nu_1 \mathbf{c} \right) \cdot \left[ \left( \lambda_2 \mathbf{a} + \mu_2 \mathbf{b} + \nu_2 \mathbf{c} \right) \times \left( \lambda_3 \mathbf{a} + \mu_3 \mathbf{b} + \nu_3 \mathbf{c} \right) \right] \\
> &= \left( \lambda_1 \mathbf{a} + \mu_1 \mathbf{b} + \nu_1 \mathbf{c} \right) \cdot \left[ \left( \lambda_2 \mu_3 - \lambda_3 \mu_2 \right) ( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} ) + \left( \mu_2 \nu_3 - \mu_3 \nu_2 \right) ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} )  + \left( \nu_2  \lambda_3 -  \nu_3 \lambda_2  \right) ( \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{a} )  \right] \\ 
> &= \lambda_1 \left( \lambda_2 \mu_3 - \lambda_3 \mu_2 \right) \big[ \mathbf{a} \cdot ( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} ) \big] + \lambda_1 \left( \mu_2 \nu_3 - \mu_3 \nu_2 \right) \big[ \mathbf{a} \cdot  ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) \big] +  \lambda_1 \left( \nu_2  \lambda_3 -  \nu_3 \lambda_2  \right) \big[ \mathbf{a} \cdot  ( \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{a} ) \big]  \\ 
> & \qquad + \mu_1  \left( \lambda_2 \mu_3 - \lambda_3 \mu_2 \right) \big[ \mathbf{b} \cdot ( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} ) \big] + \mu_1 \left( \mu_2 \nu_3 - \mu_3 \nu_2 \right) \big[ \mathbf{b} \cdot  ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) \big] +  \mu_1 \left( \nu_2  \lambda_3 -  \nu_3 \lambda_2  \right) \big[ \mathbf{b} \cdot  ( \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{a} ) \big]  \\ 
> & \qquad + \nu_1  \left( \lambda_2 \mu_3 - \lambda_3 \mu_2 \right) \big[ \mathbf{c} \cdot ( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} ) \big] + \nu_1 \left( \mu_2 \nu_3 - \mu_3 \nu_2 \right) \big[ \mathbf{c} \cdot  ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) \big] +  \nu_1 \left( \nu_2  \lambda_3 -  \nu_3 \lambda_2  \right) \big[ \mathbf{c} \cdot  ( \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{a} ) \big]  \\ 
> &= \lambda_1 \left( \mu_2 \nu_3 - \mu_3 \nu_2 \right) \big[ \mathbf{a} \cdot  ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) \big] + \mu_1 \left( \nu_2  \lambda_3 -  \nu_3 \lambda_2  \right) \big[ \mathbf{b} \cdot  ( \mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{a} ) \big]    + \nu_1  \left( \lambda_2 \mu_3 - \lambda_3 \mu_2 \right) \big[ \mathbf{c} \cdot ( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} ) \big]  \\
> &= \left[ \lambda_1 \left( \mu_2 \nu_3 - \mu_3 \nu_2 \right) + \mu_1 \left( \nu_2  \lambda_3 -  \nu_3 \lambda_2  \right) + \nu_1  \left( \lambda_2 \mu_3 - \lambda_3 \mu_2 \right)  \right] \big[ \mathbf{a} \cdot ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) \big] \\
> &= \left| \begin{matrix} \lambda_1 & \mu_1 & \nu_1 \\ \lambda_2 & \mu_2 & \nu_2 \\ \lambda_3 & \mu_3 & \nu_3 \end{matrix} \right| \mathbf{a} \cdot ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ), 
> \end{align}
> $$
> as required.

Is this solution correct? If so, is it clear enough? Or, do I need to include some more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but there is a simpler proof using [triple product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product):

$$\vec{u}.(\vec{v} \times \vec{w})=\det(u,v,w)\tag{1}$$

making the relationship to be proven equivalent to:

$$\det(A_1,A_2,A_3) \overset{?}{=} \begin{vmatrix} \lambda_1 & \mu_1 & \nu_1 \\ \lambda_2 & \mu_2 & \nu_2 \\ \lambda_3 & \mu_3 & \nu_3 \end{vmatrix} \det(a,b,c)\tag{2}$$

Now, your initial data with 3 relationships can be grouped into a *single* matrix relationship:

$$\underbrace{(A_1|A_2|A_3)}_{3 \times 3 \ \text{matrix}}=\underbrace{(a|b|c)}_{3 \times 3 \ \text{matrix}}\left(\begin{matrix} \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 \\ \mu_1 & \mu_2 & \mu_3 \\ \nu_1 & \nu_2 & \nu_3 \end{matrix} \right) \tag{3}$$

How to prove that (3) implies (2) ? Plainly by taking the determinant of both sides... (please note that in (3) we had to take the *transpose* of the matrix of coefficients, which is harmless for the computation of its determinant).

Comment: I have attempted to improve my presentation.

Comment: Why haven't you at least acknowledged my short solution ? This site is based on **mutual** exchange. I can learn also from you ...

Comment: thank you for your answer, and sorry for my being unable to respond earlier. Your answer is simply beautiful!!